# Multiple Controller classes for single request mapping in spring

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, web-services, model-view-controller

I have Controller class with more number of rest methods, so i want to split my controller class as multiple sub classes, but i want same request mapping for all the classes

Example

```
@RequestMapping("/Student")
public class StudentController {
@PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveStudnt(HttpServletRequest request)
{

}
@GetMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getStudent(HttpServletRequest request)
{

}
}
```

i want to separate these 2 methods into 2 separate controller but i want access with same request mapping /student

is this possible in spring boot?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1):

Why not? In runtime, Spring considers only final endpoints, not depend on where they are placed. You can have the same names of methods in different classes, but one path for an endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the methods in two classes but this is not a best practise as far as I know

```
public class ControllerPost {
@PostMapping(path ="/Student" consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveStudnt(HttpServletRequest request)
{
}
}
```

and

```
public class ControllerGet {
@GetMapping(path ="/Student" consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getStudent(HttpServletRequest request)
{
}
}
```